# Discount Rule if product quantity is divisible by X NopCommerce

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I'm working on a discount plugin that should apply a discount if item quantity is divisible by x and when the quanitty is not divisible by x than i should apply the discount only for the quantity that is divisible by x.

1. Example1 : x = 3
   item quantiy = 6
   result => discount applied for all items cause 6/3 = 0
2. Example2 : x = 3
   item quantiy = 5
   result => discount applied for only 3 items cause 5/3 = 1.
   Can i do all the work on a discount plugin or i should override the logic of the application of the discount that nopCommerce work with !

Thanks

Comment: Would the [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) be helpful in this scenario? You can use this operator to determine whether or item quantity is perfect divisible by x, in this case the modulo would be 0. When the modulo is not 0, you have a remainder. `5 mod 3` would be 2. A combination of the modulo and division operators should allow you to determine what quantities a discount can be applied to, and which cannot.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick response, this what i did but the application of the discount on specific quantity is my issue. this will be the discount rule but will not help on how much quantities the discount will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Perform an integer division of quantity by x. Multiply the result by x, which gives you the number of items eligible for discount.

```
items_eligible_for_discount = ((int)quantity / (int)x) * x
```

For implementing this logic in NopCommerce, you can write a discount plugin, please refer to the [documentation](https://medium.com/@nopadvance/beginners-guide-to-discount-rule-plugin-in-nopcommerce-4-20-3837abc437fc) here.

Comment: My issue is not that, in NopCommerce ther's a logic in the discounts and what we can do is discountplugin developpement wich will define the rule to check before applying the discount. Now my question is how can i tell nopCommerce that i want to apply my discount only for the items_eligible_for_discount !! i hope that i can get you my issue clearer

Comment: Updated my answer, does it help you?

Comment: the truth is that this is not what i'm looking for.